# How to implement Identity in an N-Layer solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

**This is a general question as to how one should implement Identity in an N-layer architecture, so feel free to correct my current implementation or suggest me how I can fix the current issue that I'm experiencing.**

I'm creating an ASP.net core website and I'm using the N-Layer architecture.

I've split the solution into 4 layers:

- Core Layer

  - POCO's
  - Interfaces for repositories and services.
- Business Logic Layer

  - Service implementations
- Data Access Layer

  - Entities
  - Repository implementations
- Presentation Layer

I'm sort of up the creek without a paddle, because the documentation for Identity seems somewhat obscure or at least seems to target specific use-cases.

I have installed the "**Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity**" NuGet package in the BLL and the "**Microsoft.AspNetCore.EntityFrameworkCore**" NuGet package in the DAL. Identity has connected to my db and added it's own tables. So a connection has been established.

**Issue / Scenario:**

My issue is that I might not have implemented Identity correctly, but more specifically I get an error when I try to use the Identity SignInManager from a service in the BLL.

I have the following service:

```
public class LoginService : ILoginService
{
    private readonly SignInManager<User> signInManager;

    public LoginService(SignInManager<User> signInManager)
    {
        this.signInManager = signInManager;
    }

    public async Task<SignInResult> Login(string username, string password) => await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, password, true, true);
    public async Task Logout() => await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
}
```

The service is supposed to use the Identity SignInManager (which is a generic class and I think is by default setup to use/accept the entity "UserEntity") to sign the user in/out. Ideally I should be able to use the SignInManager like so:

```
SignInManager<User>
```

But of course I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Core.Models.User]' while attempting to activate 'Services.Services.LoginService'.

If I delegate the LoginService logic to a "medieating class" in the DAL, so that I'm able to use the UserEntity, then I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'DatabaseAccess.DatabaseContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[DatabaseAccess.Entities.UserEntity,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,DatabaseAccess.DatabaseContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim`1[System.String]]'.

**Some info:**

UserEntity is only used in the DAL and is converted to the User poco.

**UserEntity**

```
public class UserEntity : IdentityUser
{
    public CompanyEntity Company { get; set; }
}
```

**User** (Atm. same props as IdentityUser)

```
public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? LockoutEnd { get; set; }
    public bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
    public bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }
    public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    public string NormalizedEmail { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string NormalizedUserName { get; set; }
    public bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
    public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
}
```

**Actual question/s:**

So have I implemented Identity correctly, or should I do it differently, and if so, how?

Also, how do I use the SignInManager correctly (what type do I specifiy)?

Comment: You are injecting `SignInManager<User>`, but your Identity Model is `UserEntity`. User is a poco unrelated to ASP.NET Core Identity. But you **shouldn't** use SignInManager or anything from ASP.NET Core identity in your domain, its infrastructure and domain should not have dependencies on Infrastructure. You have to threat your domain as if ASP.NET Core Identity doesn't exist. The `Id` from user and `UserEntity` may be the same (because the User may be your domain model, but `UserEntity` is your Identity model and identity only acts to authenticate the user (hence the name identity).

Comment: In short, you should have used `SignInManager<UserEntity>`. You can't just use arbitrary types here, only the one which you have configured with Asp.net core identity. And if you need to access something from the infrastructure, you should create an abstraction for that (interface in your service/domain/business layers, the implementation of that interface in your **APPLICATION** layer, since ASP.NET Core is infrastructure